# Play/pause is given priority to FaceTime instead of music playing applications

Tags: keyboard, facetime

I listen to music on my iMac while working.  When I get an incoming call (either FaceTime or cellular call) I want to pause the music and then answer the call (either by iMac or phone).  In a reflex I always punch the play/pause key on my keyboard (the key shared with `F8`), which at that moment doesn't pause the music but is sent to the FaceTime app to answer the call.

Which results in me not having a choice which device I want to use to answer, while the music continues to play in the background...  I can't find any setting to control this in either the Keyboard settings nor the FaceTime preferences.

How do I stop the play/pause button from being used by FaceTime to answer the call?

Comment: I realise previously people have recommended to use Mac Media Key Forwarder for similar situations as the one above.  However, I don't use iTunes nor Spotify and I actually don't mind the new "flexible" nature of play/pause button to control music and videos.  I just find that the play/pause button is not suitable for FaceTime interaction.

Comment: In the end I stopped forwarding my phone calls to my iMac.